# I'm getting an error in logcat even the app works fine?

Tags: android, logcat

my app works just like I want but I'm getting those lines error in the logcat :

```
03-15 17:21:30.176 247-476/? E/MAL-Daemon:  (     simmngr_cache_reply,  297) [SIM_MNGR]  297 EN_SIM:Non cache data request()!!
03-15 17:21:30.278 247-476/? E/MAL-Daemon:  (     simmngr_cache_reply,  297) [SIM_MNGR]  297 EN_SIM:Non cache data request()!!
03-15 17:21:30.279 247-474/? E/MAL-Daemon:  (void* rilproxy_task_hdl(,  439) rilproxy_task_hdl(), receive event = 401
03-15 17:21:30.279 247-474/? E/MAL-Daemon:  (void* rilproxy_task_hdl(,  505) RILD is disconnected
```

anyone knows what's going wrong ?

Comment: Could be a *hardware fault* around your SIM card. Hard to say, you can probably ignore it. Can occur when you flash a new ROM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These messages come from the system's radio interface layer.  They have nothing *directly* to do with your app, and do not even appear to be things that would be particularly triggered by radio (mobile data, sms, etc) operations done on behalf of your app.

Unfortunately, many Android devices ship with a lot of such "noise" still in their logs.  You may want to apply filters to see only messages specific to your application, though of course in the case of puzzling failures you should look at everything.

(If you were doing something like testing on a phone that did not have a SIM inserted, as is pretty common for everyday development devices, that could be a reason why the radio interface is being especially noisy about logging)